# Configure YII webapp after SVN checkout

Tags: svn, nginx, yii

I have a YII webapp project which I have got using `svn checkout repo`. When I try to run this webapp on my NGINX server, it (**project1**) gives me an error -

```
Application runtime path "~/workspace/project1/protected/runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.
```

But when I create some other YII project (**project2**) like -

```
yiic webapp ~/workspace/project2
#and then the MVC procedure
./protected/yiic shell
>>model User users
>>crud User
```

I can run my webapp in my browser.

Is it because the *project1* is not configured? What do I have to do the configuration manually to my `working copy`?

Comment: It didn't help. I can't even run the `project1/index.php`

Comment: ignore my previous comments, the only thing needed would be to allow the nginx user to write to the *runtime* folder, my mistake about the renaming, sorry.

Comment: yes. thanks. couldn't figure it out from `make sure it is a directory writable`. thought it was yii thing and not unix thing. put something in ans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give write access to the *runtime* folder, for the nginx user.

Yii uses this folder for storing temporary files during runtime, from [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.convention#directory):

> WebRoot/protected/runtime: this directory holds private temporary files generated during runtime of the application. This directory must be writable by Web server process.

So, yii does this check, in [CApplication's `setRuntimePath()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/base/CApplication.php#L268) :

```
if(($runtimePath=realpath($path))===false || !is_dir($runtimePath) || !is_writable($runtimePath))
```

Comment: yes. it worked. why was this dir write protected and not the others. should we delete the comments referring the `.htaccess`

Comment: Actually all the folders are protected, but yii uses this folder to store temporary files during runtime, that's why write access is needed, see updated answer. yeah you can delete those messages

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `yiic webapp` command to set the permissions in your checked out project, assuming you have `yii/framework` in the same relative path as in your development project.

```
svn checkout http://domain.tld/myproject myproject
cd myproject
protected/yiic webapp .
```

**Just make sure you do not overwrite existing files.**

Comment: good. +1 for you. but I needed the same project - _project1_ as my yii webapp. I just needed to change the permissions of `runtime/`.

Comment: ... and `assets/` ... and `data/` (if you've a SQLite Database) ;)